# Reading word document

Tags: php

This works with vs < office 2007 and its pure PHP, no COM crap, still trying to figure 2007

Hi,i am using office 2007.so the code above is not working in office 2007.can any one please suggest what changes should be made in order to work.

Answer (score 1):

The format for Office 2007 and later is XML.  You can access it's format using any number of XML libraries available to PHP.  For more details on the namespaces, etc. of the format, check out [MS's documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa338205.aspx).

Answer (score 0):

office 2007 uses ziped xml files. The format is way different to previous versions I believe.